# How to set my webapp to appear as ROOTfor localhost:8080

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, deployment, root, contextpath

I've got a webapp in my Tomcat/webapps directory. My app's directory is "site" and is showing as http:localhost:8080/site

I'd like to have the site show as http://localhost:8080/

I've read the docs and tried creating a ROOT.xml file in my Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost directory to create a ROOT context path but the connection isn't being made.

Can someone nudge me in the right direction? Here's the content of that ROOT.xml file.

```
<Context  docBase="site" path="/"> </Context>
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest approach to getting root context would be to simply rename your app's directory from `webapps/site` to `webapps/ROOT` and restart Tomcat. If there's already a ROOT app in your default `webapps` folder, then you need to create another Host, because there may be only one root context app per Host.

Another option (again, if you don't already have a ROOT app under `webapps`) would be to edit your `conf/server.xml` file and add your context element within the default `<Host>`:

```
<Context path="" docBase="site" />
```

If you'd like to create a separate host, then you'll need to define a second `<Host>` in `server.xml`, e.g.,

```
<Host name="anotherhost" appBase="webapps_anotherhost"></Host>
```

For the above to work, you'd need to create a `webapps_anotherhost` folder as a sibling folder next to your default host's `webapps` folder, and then drop your WAR in that folder, either as an exploded directory named `ROOT` or a compressed WAR named `ROOT.war`. Then restart Tomcat and browse your application at `http://anotherhost:8080` (you'll also a hosts file entry, of course).

These are just a few of the many options. The Tomcat docs are fairly detailed about this stuff. You can find the docs for your version of Tomcat at http://tomcat.apache.org/.