# Replace the URL of a HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets

So I wrote a simple servlet to playback a video to the client. The client would request something like localhost:8080/myApp/resources/testVideo.mkv. But I want to completely replace that URL by the direct URl to the file, e.g:testWebsite.com/testVideo.mkv. I have no idea how I would even do sth like that. Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Is testWebsite.com running on the same server as "localhost" (in your example above)? It isn't clear if you are running both an app server (e.g. Tomcat) on port 8080 and/or a webserver (like Apache httpd) on port 80 (testWebsite.com).

Comment: testWebsite is just a name I give. The mkv is actually hosted on one of the cloud service website and it has CDN enabled.So if you put that mkv link into a  browser, it would start playing. I just want to know how to access it through my app and return that url back to the client

Answer (score 1):

In web.xml, you can map your servlet to all files ending in *.mkv

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myVideoServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.mkv</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In order to also remove the "myApp" part of the URL, you have to install your web application into the ROOT context (here are [instructions how to do that if you use Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668719/how-to-set-my-webapp-to-appear-as-rootfor-localhost8080)). That way, it gets to serve all URL for the whole site.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can look at is a request wrapper: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html